# How to figure out the scale for a vertical timeline

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a vertical timeline of events that are ordered from newest to oldest and I need to dynamically create a vertical timeline and add these events to it with scaled intervals. The timeline's length should probably be adjusted based on the number of events and how spread out the time's between these events are.

Each event has a ruby datetime attribute. I just need help on how to figure out the length of the timeline and what the scale of intervals would be. The events can occur anywhere from seconds to days to months apart.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most graphs have even intervals on their axes. Why not take `(dateEnd - dateStart) / 10`?